# trying to create product list with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery

I need to make a list of products and want to be able to add number of products independently directly on list with two + - buttons. Here is code...

**HTML**

```
<ul data-role="listview">
   <li data-icon="false"><a href="">
       <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" /> text, text</a>
           <div data-role="fieldcontain">
              <button class="plus" id="1" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">Plus</button>
              <button class="minus" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="notext">Minus</button>
               <p class="p"><span class="number">0</span></p>
         </div>
   </li>
   <li data-icon="false"><a href="">
       <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" />text, text</a>
           <div data-role="fieldcontain">
               <button class="plus" id="1" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">Plus</button>
               <button class="minus" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="notext">Minus</button>
               <p class="p"><span class="number">0</span></p>
           </div>
     </li>
     <li data-icon="false"><a href="">
         <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" />text, text</a>
             <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <button class="plus" id="1" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">Plus</button>
                <button class="minus" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="notext">Minus</button>
                <p class="p"><span class="number">0</span></p>
            </div>
     </li>
</ul>
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Order</a>
<a href="#home" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Home</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
var $number = 0;

$('.plus').click(function () {
    $number++;
    $('.number').text($number).css('color', '#97bf0d');
});

$('.minus').click(function () {
    if($number > 0){
        $number--;
    }
    $('.number').text($number);
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Skc9w/1/)

Comment: First things first, remove the ID from the plus buttons, or make them unique.  Since you're not using it in the supplied javascript I can't tell you which is more relevant, but you should not have duplicate IDs.

Comment: true, that came by mistake, tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is your updated code. You need to take span with number class of that current li only. So I have used closest function of jquery to find parent li of that button and updating span .number and also need to take current value of span.number as it has specific values based on li item

```
var $number = 0;
$('.plus').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $number = parseInt($(this).closest('li').find('.number').text());
    $number++;
    $(this).closest('li').find('.number').text($number).css('color', '#97bf0d');
});

$('.minus').click(function () {
    $number = parseInt($(this).closest('li').find('.number').text());
    if ($number > 0) {
        $number--;
    }
    $(this).closest('li').find('.number').text($number);
});
```

Check this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Skc9w/2/)